# Getting keys with maximum value in JavaScript hashmap/object

Tags: javascript, object, key, reduce

Example:

```
hash = {'Apple':2, 'Orange' :1 , 'Mango' : 2}
```

here the maximum key is both Apple and Mango. How do I write a function which gives both Apple and Mango as answer.

I tried something like this :

```
Object.keys(hash).reduce(function(a, b){ return hash[a] > hash[b] ? a : b });
```

But this gives only Apple as the answer.

Comment: so you want to return an array?

Comment: Yes, sorry i should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could first calculate the max value as a separate operation and then just filter:

```js
const hash = {Apple: 2, Orange: 1, Mango: 2};

const max = Object.keys(hash).reduce((a, v) => Math.max(a, hash[v]), -Infinity);
const result = Object.keys(hash).filter(v => hash[v] === max);

console.log(result);
```

Simple and readable, but it requires and extra iteration, so it's not the most efficient implementation.

Comment: Can you please explain why have you used -Infinity in the reduce function,I didnt understand that.

Comment: You need to initialize the maximum value with something. That can be `0` if you're only dealing with positive values. I chose negative infinity, because any value will be greater than negative infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You might transform the object into one whose properties correspond to the count, whose values are the (original) property names in an array, and then get the value of the property with the maximum count:

```js
const hash = {'Apple':2, 'Orange' :1 , 'Mango' : 2};
const indexedByCount = Object.entries(hash).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
  if (!a[val]) a[val] = [];
  a[val].push(key);
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(
  indexedByCount[Math.max(...Object.keys(indexedByCount))]
);
```

A less functional but more efficient method would be to keep track of a `max` variable corresponding to the maximum value found so far:

```js
const hash = {'Apple':2, 'Orange' :1 , 'Mango' : 2};
let max = -Infinity;
console.log(
  Object.entries(hash).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    if (val > max) {
      max = val;
      return [key];
    }
    if (val === max) a.push(key);
    return a;
  }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `reduce` can only return a single value, but you need an *array* of values. So create one as the initial value.

In your function body, first, check whether your next key has a larger value, in which case you clear out the array.

Then, if your array is empty, or if the first contained key (and thus all keys) have the same value, push that key into your array.

Also, it helps if you give your arguments more expressive names.

```
Object.keys(hash).reduce(function(longestKeys, key){
  if(hash[key] > hash[longestKeys[0]]){
    longestKeys.length = 0;
  }

  if(longestKeys.length === 0 || hash[key] === hash[longestKeys[0]]){
    longestKeys.push(key);
  }

  return longestKeys;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. If `max` changes clear the result and set only the `max` value.

```js
var hash = {'Apple':2, 'Orange':1 , 'Mango':2, "Jackfruit":10, "Pineapple":5, "Tomato":-4};
var max="";

var result = Object.keys(hash).reduce(function(acc, val){
    if(max < hash[val]) (max=hash[val], acc={});
    if(hash[val]==max) acc[val] = hash[val];
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the requirements are traverse the array only once and results is an array of keys

```
const hash = {'Apple':2, 'Orange' :1 , 'Mango' : 2};
let max = 0;
let result = [];

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(hash).forEach(k => {
  if (hash[k] > max) {
    result = [k];
    max = hash[k];
  } else if (hash[k] === max) {
    result.push(k);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```